# How to deserialise a JSON subtype using Jackson with one case of not having a type id

Tags: java, jackson

I am using an external service who sends a response in the following structure

In the case of Success:

```
{
  "executionTime": ""
  "result": <subclass of ObjectBase which has type id>
}
```

In case of Failure:

```
{
  "executionTime": ""
  "result": {
     "error": <ErrorResult which is subtype of ObjectBase>
  }
}
```

In case of failure, there is not type id directly in the result object and Jackson deserialization is failing.

I tried using defaultImpl but end up with this error

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class ErrorResponse not subtype of [simple type, class ObjectBase]

```
    public class Response<T> {

        private APIException error;
        private T result;

        public Response(T result, APIException error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.result = result;
        }
    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, visible = true, property = ParamKeys.OBJECT_TYPE, defaultImpl = ErrorResponse.class)
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = ObjectTypes.VALUE, value = Value.class),
    })
    public class ObjectBase implements Serializable {
    }
```

How can we deserialize this without any hack in a clean way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is `ErrorResult` wrapped in an object already saying "error"? Shouldn't it be `"result":<ErrorResult which is subtype of ObjectBase>`?

Comment: Well as mentioned I am using a 3rd party service who have designed the result that way